# Wordpress blog isn't showing posts. Does adding a custom portfolio post field effect this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Now I've done this a couple other times with no problem, I have a main page using home.php and the blog as another page using "blog-home.php" blog template with all the right code to grab the posts but it's not displaying. The only difference is I've added a custom portfolio post field to the functions, would this be effecting it or could it be something else? I can access a post from the home page under latest post putting the code below but that's it.

```
<?php query_posts("post_per_page=1"); the_post(); ?> 
  <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?></div>
```

**UPDATE: I've tried another code but now it is only displaying the blog page as a post. **

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Blog Home
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'Blog', 'posts_per_page' => 5   ) ); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="blogentry">
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  </h4>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <div class="postmetadata">
                        <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

            <h2>Not Found</h2>

            <?php endif; ?>


</div>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a custom field would prevent posts, but have you linked the blog-home template to the page?

Comment: Yes I have, I've edited the post with the code I have that's worked for all my other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use

```
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 1));
global $post;
$post = $posts[0];
the_excerpt();
```

instead

```
query_posts();
```

is never a good idea change the global query if get_posts dosn't work for you try with WP_Query()